# Curve Fitting for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, interpolation

Let $a_n\searrow 0$ be a strictly decreasing sequence. Is it always possible to find a $C^2$ or even $C^\infty$ function $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ so that $f$ is strictly decreasing and $f(n)=a_n$ for all $n$?

Could a cubic spline do that?

Comment: Well if you don't insist on analyticity, it would be pretty easy to construct a $C^\infty$ function with these properties and $f^{k}(n) = 0$ for $k>0$.

Comment: So is there a reference for this fact?

Comment: Maybe this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $C_2$ cubic spline won't work. There are many examples of monotone data sequences for which the interpolating $C_2$ cubic spline is not monotone.

There are several ways to construct a monotone cubic spline (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation)), but these curves are typically just $C_1$, not $C_2$.